# How to change the layout of dataframe pivot in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My data frame looks like below

```
Name | Date | Price | Disc%  
A    | 8/29 | 100.0 | 5  
B    | 8/29 | 88.80 | 6  
A    | 8/30 | 99.0  | 4  
B    | 8/30 | 85.0  | 3
```

If I use

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='name',columns='Date',values=['price','disc']...),
```

I get the top header differently with first all dates for Price displayed and then all dates for discount.

```
    Price         ||   Disc%  
    ----------------------------------  
    8/29 | 8/30    | 8/29   | 8/30  
A    100 | 99.0    | 5      | 4  
B   88.80|  85.0   | 6      | 3
```

I need a pivot like below  (with columns - dates on top)

```
    8/29           ||   8/30  
    ----------------------------------  
    Price | Disc%  | Price  | Disc%  
A    100  |  5     | 99.0   | 4  
B    88.80|  6     | 85.0   | 3  

Any suggestions appreciated.
```

> Please ignore any formatting errors or column headers in the tables above

Answer (score 2):

Use [`swaplevels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

```
pivoted.swaplevel(-1,-2, 1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
Date  8/29         8/30      
     Disc%  Price Disc% Price
Name                         
A        5  100.0     4  99.0
B        6   88.8     3  85.0
```

Comment: rafaelc and Andy - That's simply awesome, was struggling to find what to search for in google. Thanks for your help!!